# My dropdown menu is pushing other html elements downwards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a project and I added a dropdown menu on navbar and I don't know why that it seems to push the HTML down when toggled. I tried making its position absolute and top 100% but it didn't work, I am using bootstrap, please help

Here is the main HTML

```css
body{
    background-color: #0b0c10!important;
}


nav{
    background-color: #0b0c10!important;
    color: turquoise;
    text-decoration: none;

}

nav a{
    color: turquoise;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Lato', sclear-serif;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.navbar-nav{
    margin-right: 80px;
    text-align: center!important;
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 30px!important;
    margin-left: 30px;

}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Calcify</a>
  </button> 
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          More Calculator
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add jquery.min.js, popper.min.js, and bootstrap.min.js.

In the introduction of Bootstrap it states which imports you need to add. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start

You have to add some scripts in order to get bootstrap fully working. It's important that you include them in this exact order. Popper.js is one of them:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/shradhaa/pen/QWNQRjE)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Calcify</a>
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      More Calculator
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul></nav>

.navbar{
  align-items: stretch!important;
 }
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
 }
```

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: Please check the example link that I have posted. Is that how you want to achieve?

Comment: No, Whenever I use it on mobile device, the dropdown shifts the containers down

Comment: Please add  to your CSS file .navbar{ align-items: stretch!important; }  and .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
}

Comment: Yes, it did the work after doing this,but I had to mark the position move important  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu { position: absolute;!important }

Comment: Yes, you have to do so, to override the bootstrap css.

Comment: @Ketsmania, Can you upvote if you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

for your dropdown items list use

```
position:absolute;
z-index:5;
```

this worked for me

Answer (score -1):

```css
body{
    background-color: #0b0c10!important;
}


nav{
    background-color: #0b0c10!important;
    color: turquoise;
    text-decoration: none;

}

nav a{
    color: turquoise;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Lato', sclear-serif;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.navbar-nav{
    margin-right: 80px;
    text-align: center!important;
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 30px!important;
    margin-left: 30px;

}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Calcify</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
     
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          More Calculator
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
     
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: both question and solution looks similar, what's the difference?

Comment: He forgot to add  the `<button>` part he only use `</button>`

Comment: but then , this is still not the solution. Also while answering try explaining what you did and what was the mistake

Comment: I have tried it and that works perfectly well. Maybe there could be another CSS class that overwrites the working code.

Comment: The solution is answered in the above answer's comment. P.S. The </button> was a mistake, but nothing to do with my problem.